# Where i can find information about updates

Tags: 12.04, updates

Some minutes ago I gained "restar to updates take effect"(don't remember exectly the words). But I didn't see update program window. I by my self runing this program. Result: last information about updates - 1 day ago. May be it becouse my time 00:44 AM. But no settings allow to install updates without my "last word". But i have installed gnome more settings(themes and icons and... So wher i can find information about -- What was update?

Answer (score 0):

The package manager keeps logs in `/var/log/apt`. You can see changes made with:

```
cd /var/log/apt
cat history.log
```

Depending on how long since the upgrade, the relevant entries may have been compressed to save space. The `/var/log/apt` directory will contain archived log files named `history.log.X.gz` where larger values of X mean older log files. You can read the compressed log files using `zcat` without needing to manually uncompress them:

```
cd /var/log/apt
zcat history.log.1.gz
```

You should see lines like

```
Upgrade: package1:arch (oldversion, newversion), package2:arch (oldversion, newversion)...
```

from which it should be fairly easy to see what was upgraded recently.